# Uploading an image and store it within the webpage temporarily using the said site

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

tried everything within the site, tested it, followed instructions but to no avail, where did i go wrong?

site: http://www.xul.fr/en/html5/filereader.php

what i'm trying to do is upload an image and store it within the webpage temporarily via javascript or without using any server, i tried compiling the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) 
  document.write("<b>File API supported.</b> <br />");
else
  document.write('<i>File API not supported by this browser.</i> <br />');
</script>

<form name="form1" method="post" action>
    <input type="file" id="getimage">
</form>

<script language="javascript" >

function imageHandler(e2) 
{ 
    var store = document.getElementById('imgstore');
    store.innerHTML='<img src="' + e2.target.result +'">';
}
function loadimage(e1)
{
    var filename = e1.target.files[0]; 
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = imageHandler;  
    fr.readAsDataURL(filename); 
}
window.onload=function()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("filebrowsed");
    x.addEventListener('change', readfile, false);
    var y = document.getElementById("getimage");
    y.addEventListener('change', loadimage, false);
}

</script>

<fieldset><legend>Your image here</legend>
    <div  id="imgstore">
    </div>
</fieldset>

</html>
```

i figured he has some embedded scripts or i don't know i practically followed what he said
any heads up? or any ideas?

OT: sorry for the vague post before, not feeling well, and not in the mood, but i need to make this work thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off I don't see the correct HTML elements on your page, nor do I see a "readfile" function that you've hooked up to the event listener on x.

Second, you aren't uploading the image, you are reading it. And you aren't storing the image, you're displaying it.

Now that's out of the way.

To use the File reader we need a input type="file". As you correctly copied, we need to add an event listener onto that element listening for a "change" event. Inside of the function hooked up to the event listener we need to create a FileReader object and readAsDataURL the data from the event. Check, we got that too. Now we can hook up the function for the finished loading on the Reader object. Inside this function we want to create a new Image() and assign the src property of it to the result of the FileReaders load. To display the image we need to listen for the load event on the image as well, where we just append the image to the page wherever it needs to go.

So the code might look something like this.

```
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('getimage');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);


function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}
```